# Symfony2 Requests concurrency

Tags: mongodb, symfony, session, concurrency

I have a problem connected to Symfony2 requests. When I do a request, a process, loading data from MongoDB, starts. If I open a new tab in the browser, and I do any request to the application (also to different routes), though I've closed the old tab, a blank page apperas, waiting for response.

The session management is native. I would the new request killing all the processes already running. Is not a problem of session concurrency, because I want a 'last will win' approach. I think the problem is connetcted to the request handling of the HttpKernel, but I'm not able to solve it. Can you help me?

This is the controller action:

```
/**
     * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request, $page = null)
    {
        //controlla la lista di autorizzazioni: l'utente può eseguire l'action solo se autorizzato per quell'attributo
        if ($this->authlist != null) {
            $authorized = false;
            foreach ($this->authlist as $auth) {
                if ($this->security_auth_checker->isGranted($auth, new VoterHelper())) {
                    $authorized = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!$authorized) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Accesso negato! L'utente non può accedere a questa funzionalità !");
            }
        }

        //recupera i dati
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $form = $this->formFactory->create($this->formType);

        $sessionNamePage = $this->formType->getName().'_page';
        if (($page) && ($session->get($this->formType->getName()))) {
            $form_data = $session->get($this->formType->getName());
            $form->setData($form_data);
            $session->set($sessionNamePage, $page);
        } else {
            $session->remove($sessionNamePage);
        }

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $form_data = $form->getData();
        }

        //passa alla business logic i parametri della form, i dati di paginazione e offset ed eventualmente la queryString del metodo get
        if (isset($form_data)) {
            $queryString = $request->getQueryString();

//             $form_data['page'] = $page;
//             $form_data['offset'] = self::OFFSET;

            $data = array();
            $data['form_data'] = $form_data;
            $data['page'] = $page;
            $data['offset'] = self::OFFSET;
            $data['query_string'] = $queryString;

            $results = $this->businessLogic->execute($data);

            if (is_array($results) && isset($results['reportsCounts'])) {
                $form_data['report_count'] = $results['reportsCounts'];
                $reports = $results['reports'];
            } else {
                $reports = $results;
            }
        }

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //          $form_data = $form->getData();
            $session->set($this->formType->getName(), $form_data);
            $sessionNamePage = $this->formType->getName().'_page';
            if (!$session->get($sessionNamePage)) {
                $session->set($sessionNamePage, 1);
            }
        }

        return $this->templating->renderResponse($this->templatePath, array(
                'report_count' => (isset($form_data['report_count'])) ? $form_data['report_count'] : null,
                'reports' => (isset($reports)) ? $reports : null,
                'page' => $page,
                'offset' => self::OFFSET,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you share the code which you are using?

Comment: If I analyze the profiler, it seems that the problem is the Security Firewall, that waits for response....

Comment: How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by calling

```
$request->getSession()->save();
```

brefore any long-time process.

In this way, I've forced Symfony to unlock the session files.